# Does TypeScript have a dedicated VM, or is it compile-to-js only?

Tags: typescript

If not, any plans to deliver a server-side and/or browser-embedded VM?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nope - There's no dedicated VM, and no plan to develop one, either.  The goal of TypeScript is to help us all build better JS applications, regardless of where they run.  As JS VMs improve, we improve as well :)

Comment: Good decision, and nice job btw :). I can easily see myself switching some code from coffee to TS very fast, I guess I'll miss the (for x in []) and (for k, v of {}) contructs, any plans to implement these with the foreach keyword for example?

Comment: Thanks! The language is still evolving, but generally we want to err on the side of where the standards are going.  ES6-style destructuring is likely something we'll be thinking about moving forward.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. I'll take a look at ES proposals to have a clue about TS direction then.

Comment: Worth noting that, as I understand it, since the TS compiler is written in TS, it can be compiled to JS, which would allow you to compile TS on the fly in the browser, which would allow you to skip the dev-time compile step, which would provide all the workflow benefits of a TS VM without actually requiring one (although presumably at the expense of some overhead).

Comment: Actually, if enough people start using TS then browsers could start to do optimizations on TS scripts directly and optimize a lot better when the VM knows about type information etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Deno](https://deno.land/). It transparently incorporates a TypeScript to JavaScript transpiler, so to you as end-user it [appears as if it was running TypeScript directly](https://deno.land/manual@v1.30.3/advanced/typescript/overview).

By default, TypeScript code is *not type checked* before it is executed, since this can take quite a long time. If you want type checking, enable it by adding `--check` to the command, e.g.

```
deno run --check module.ts
# or also type check remote modules and npm packages
deno run --check=all module.ts
```